# How to extract pixel information from PNG using javascript (getImageData alternatives)

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png

I am trying to get pixel data from PNG images for processing. The current way is by using `canvas.drawImage` followed `canvas.getImageData` ([example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528299/get-pixel-color-of-base64-png-using-javascript)). I am looking for alternatives.

The problem with the current approach is that browsers modify pixel values influenced by *alpha*, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11601302/html5-canvas-to-png-zeroes-all-channels-when-alpha-transparent) and [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/352957-canvas-how-to-prevent-zero-alpha-from-zeroing-rgb-channels/).

This question has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17228724/how-to-convert-a-png-base64-string-to-pixel-array-without-using-canvas-getimaged), but no satisfactory answers are available.

Comment: can you just set the alpha to opaque, so that it works like you want?

Comment: The original PNG is actually a greyscale image. The RGBA values are set by the browser when `drawImage` is called.

Comment: loop the pixels and set the A channel sub-pixels to 255, then run getImageData() again. should work fine

Comment: Yeah. Or just write some code to parse PNG files and read it as binary dat... Nope, setting alpha to 255 sounds like a pretty good idea.

Comment: To modify the A channel, I have to do this `buffer = ctx.getImageData(0,0,img.width,img.height.data);`. By then, `buffer` is already all zeros.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only way to do this without using canvas and `getImageData()` is to load the PNG file as a binary typed array and parse the file in code "manually".

**Prerequisites:**

- For this you need the PNG specification which you can find **[here](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/iso/index-object.html)**.
- You need to know how to use typed arrays (for this a `DataView` is the most suitable view).
- PNG files are *chunk* based and you will need to know how to parse chunks

A typical chunk based file has a four byte header called a FourCC identifier, followed by the size and misc. data depending on the file format definition.

Then *chunks* are placed right after this containing often a FOURCC (or four character code) and then the size of the chunk without the chunk header. In principle:

```
    MAGIC FOURCC
    SIZE/MISC    - depending on definition
    ...

    CHK1         - Chunk FourCC
    SIZE         - unsigned long
    .... data

    CHK2
    SIZE
    .... data
```

This format principle came originally from the Commodore Amiga platform and EA/IFF (Interleaved File Format) back in mid 80's.

But in modern days some vendors has extended or vary the chunk format, so for PNG chunks it will actually look like this:

Header (always 8 bytes and the same byte values):

```
‰PNG       (first byte is 0x89, see specs for reason)
CR + LF    0x0C0A
EOC + LF   0x1A0A
```

Chunks:

```
SIZE      (4 bytes, may be 0 (f.ex. IEND). Excl. chunk header and crc)
FOURCC    (4 bytes, ie. "IHDR", "IDAT")
[...data] (length: SIZE x bytes)
CRC32     (4 bytes representing the CRC-32 checksum of the data)
```

(see the referenced specification link above for details).

And the byte-order (endianess) for PNG is always big-endian ("network" order).

This makes it easy to parse through the file supporting only some (or all) chunks. For PNG you would need to support at least ([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#.22Chunks.22_within_the_file)):

- `IHDR` must be the first chunk; it contains (in this order) the image's width, height, bit depth and color type.
- `IDAT` contains the image, which may be split between multiple IDAT chunks. Such splitting increases the file size slightly, but makes it easier to stream the PNG. The IDAT chunk contains the actual image data, which is the output stream of the compression algorithm.
- `IEND` marks the file end.

If you intend to support palette (color indexed) files you would also need to support the `PLTE` chunk. When you parse the IHDR chunk you will be able to see what color format is used (type 2 for RGB data, or 6 for RGBA and so on).

Parsing is itself easy so your biggest challenge would be supporting things like ICC profiles (when present in the `iCCP` chunk) to adjust the image color data. A typical chunk is the gamma chunk (`gAMA`) which contains a single gamma value you can apply to convert the data to linear format so that it displays correctly when display gamma is applied (there are also other special chunks related to colors).

The second biggest challenge would be the *decompression* which uses INFLATE. You can use a project such as **[PAKO zlib port](https://github.com/nodeca/pako)** to do this job for you and this port has performance close to native zlib. In addition to that, if you want to do error checking on the data (recommended) CRC-32 checking should also be supported.

For security reason you should always check that fields contain the data they're suppose to as well as that reserved space are initialized with either 0 or the defined data.

Hope this helps!

**Example chunk parser:** (note: won't run in IE).

```js
function pngParser(buffer) {

  var view = new DataView(buffer),
      len = buffer.byteLength,
      magic1, magic2,
      chunks = [],
      size, fourCC, crc, offset,
      pos = 0;  // current offset in buffer ("file")

  // check header
  magic1 = view.getUint32(pos); pos += 4;
  magic2 = view.getUint32(pos); pos += 4;

  if (magic1 === 0x89504E47 && magic2 === 0x0D0A1A0A) {

    // parse chunks
    while (pos < len) {

      // chunk header
      size = view.getUint32(pos);
      fourCC = getFourCC(view.getUint32(pos + 4));

      // data offset
      offset = pos + 8;
      pos = offset + size;

      // crc
      crc = view.getUint32(pos);
      pos += 4;

      // store chunk
      chunks.push({
        fourCC: fourCC,
        size: size,
        offset: offset,
        crc: crc
      })
    }

    return {chunks: chunks}
  } 
  else {
      return {error: "Not a PNG file."}
  }

  function getFourCC(int) {
    var c = String.fromCharCode;
    return c(int >>> 24) + c(int >>> 16 & 0xff) + c(int >>> 8 & 0xff) + c(int & 0xff);
  }
}

// USAGE: ------------------------------------------------

fetch("//i.imgur.com/GP6Q3v8.png")
  .then(function(resp) {return resp.arrayBuffer()}).then(function(buffer) {

  var info = pngParser(buffer);

  // parse each chunk here...
  for (var i = 0, chunks = info.chunks, chunk; chunk = chunks[i++];) {
    out("CHUNK : " + chunk.fourCC);
    out("SIZE  : " + chunk.size + " bytes");
    out("OFFSET: " + chunk.offset + " bytes");
    out("CRC   : 0x" + (chunk.crc>>>0).toString(16).toUpperCase());
    out("-------------------------------");
  }

  function out(txt) {document.getElementById("out").innerHTML += txt + "<br>"}
});
```

```css
body {font: 14px monospace}
```

```html
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

From here you can extract the IHDR to find image size and color type, then IDAT chunk(s) to deflate (PNG uses filters per scanline which do complicate things a bit, as well as a interlace mode, see specs) and your almost done ;)

Comment: Wow!! That is an elaborate answer, and as you said, it is a project on its own. Maybe it's time to rethink my strategy.

Comment: @ahmohamed it can indeed be a large project, but depending on how much you want to support. I added a working example PNG chunk walker which can be used to extract the needed data (just note I didn't add much error checking which is necessary for production of course)

Comment: tons of thanks to you. That far more that I had hoped for when I asked the question. I will try to wrap my head around it and decide how to go.

Comment: `pngparse` library is only for node.js. How can I use it on client side?

Comment: @ahmohamed if you are not afraid of alpha version, I have now made [pngtoy](https://github.com/epistemex/pngtoy) which can read and parse PNG files++ (note: it currently fails with interlaced and some special cases). Have a look - works on client side. See tests folder for details.